# How to use expression enquo() in annotate function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function which returns with no errors a ggplot graph using expression !!enquo():

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

f <- function (df, x, y) {
 df %>%
   ggplot(aes(!!enquo(x), !!enquo(y)))+
   geom_point()
}

f (mtcars, cyl, disp)
```

I want to select the last point on the graph by adding the next geom:

```
 annotate('point', x=dplyr::last(!!enquo(x)), 
 y=dplyr::last(!!enquo(y)), color='#FF0000', size = 1.5)
```

And I get an error:

```
Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation 
context.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
f <- function (df, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  df %>%
    ggplot(aes(!!x, !!y)) + geom_point() + 
    annotate("point", 
             x = summarise(df, last(!!x)) %>% unlist(), 
             y = summarise(df, last(!!y)) %>% unlist(), 
             color = "#FF0000", size = 1.5)
}
f(mtcars, cyl, disp)
```

Comment: if x has a date format use: as.Date(summarise(data, last(!!x)) %>% unlist())